# Redirect https to https in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I created a quote form on an https server that did not work, so I need to redirect that url to the new https server that works...

redirect permanant https://www.my-url.com/quotes/ to https://new-quote-form-url.com/quotes/

I tried this in my .htaccess file but it did not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Did not work as in...? Didn't redirect? Gave an error message? ...?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

`redirect permanent https://www.my-url.com/quotes/ https://new-quote-form-url.com/quotes/`

Note that I removed 'to' and you spelt permanent incorrectly.

Comment: I tried that and it does not work. I only have .htaccess in the http://www.my-url.com site.

Comment: Is it even enabled in httpd.conf ? Do you have access to the apache web server ? If you do, then you can enable it (if it isnt already) by opening httpd.conf and changing "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All". Restart the web server after making the change. If you dont have access to the web server configuration files then contact the administrator of the server.